# Apache how to set company proxy to location

Tags: proxy, apache, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

i am trying to set a ProxyPass to my Apache server. I want to set the / location to http://google.de. The problem is, that i am running against the company's proxy server and i need to 'tell' my Apache server that it should use the company proxy server.

This is what i configured:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass / http://www.google.de
ProxyPassReverse / http://www.google.de
```

is there something like a "setProxy" order? for example the proxyserver of my company is: proxy.company.com:81.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, one just need to add the ProxyRemote command:

```
ProxyRemote * http://proxy.mycompany.com:81

<Location /test>     
ProxyPass http://www.heise.de
ProxyPassReverse http://www.heise.de
</Location>
```

That should work fine. The only problem is, that the relative paths make trouble. I can´t see images and the links are dead.